# Display three button horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I am displaying 3 buttons horizontally,
[image]

My code is working fine

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/acll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/approve_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/verify_d"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/delete_d"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/modify_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/modify_d"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I am using `RelativeLayout` inside a `LinearLayout`, and then putting button inside `RelativeLayout`, if I use only `LinearLayout` with `weightSum` then all 3 button occupies whole width.

My question: Please let me know any other way to achieve the same task without using nesting layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi  test this code i just have wrote it :

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/acll"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/approve_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/verify_d" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/delete_d" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/modify_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/modify_d" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create it using only relative layout.

**1.** Align first button to the left using `alignParentLeft="true"`

**2.** Align the middle button using `centerInParent="true"`

**3.** Align the third button to the right using `alignParentRight="true".`

You can then add your desired padding/margin.
Also add gravity center_vertical to all three buttons.

Comment: aligning left or right, will display the button to top left and at top right, it wont display as i mentioned in image in question. Thanks for your support

Comment: Well you can always set gravity with the buttons for the same. Provide center_vertical gravity to the buttons

Comment: yes, I did, but its not working as i mentioned in the image, if you have some time, will you help me

Answer (score 1):

Just add `Layout weight =1`   with `layout_width match_parent`

**strong text**  Also Add Weight sum to parent layout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConstraintLayout. Check the links below:
 1. https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1
 2. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: you should avoid posting link only answers. Link may become dead and then your answer will be pretty much of no use. It's better to include important contents from the links into your answer and provide link for further references

Comment: But if the links are dead, he can search for the ConstraintLayout as I mentioned :P